# How to expose panoramas as an album when picking photos albums

Tags: ios, panoramas, mpmediapickercontroller, alassetsgroup

I'd like to expose a panoramic photo album in my custom picker as Apple Photo just does.

How would you do that, provided I find nothing about a special dedicated ALAssetsGroup?

Comment: I have this same question...

Comment: Alas, the only way I see is to evaluate form factor w/h and to determine something like if w/f > 4 it's probably a panorama. The weak point here, is that we're not sure the user cropped his photo. We can't assume a cylinder projection was plied to the photo.